# Declaration of templated class member function returning a map

Tags: c++

In VC++ 2015 I have an untemplated class which should have a templated memberfunction which returns a map.

Here is a bit of the code:

```
class Registry
{
    template<class configclass>
    std::map<std::wstring, configclass> enumerateSubKeys(std::wstring subKeyName);
}
```

But the compiler throws error messages:
error C2988: Unrecognized template declaration/definition
error C2143: Syntax error: missing ";" before "<"
error C2238: Unexpected Token before ";"
error C2059: Syntax error: "<"

I assume my problem is in having to use a map where the wstring has to be fixed/untemplated but the second argument is my template class.

Of course i followed the compilers suggestions but that didn't get me any further.

Comment: Compiles fine if I add a `;` at the end of the class definition. Those errors might be related to that.

Comment: @Kevin Won't compile fine without including certain header files.

Comment: True, perhaps I wrongly assumed they were included above the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include <map>` and add a semi-colon to the end of your class declaration.

As @Kevin and @juanchopanza have pointed out in the comments, you are simply missing a semi-colon and potentially an include. With the following program in VS2013:

```
class Registry
{
    template<class configclass>
    std::map<std::wstring, configclass> enumerateSubKeys(std::wstring subKeyName);
}

int main()
{
}
```

I get an assortment of the errors you listed:

> error C2143 : syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>   error C2238 : unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   error C2988 : unrecognizable template declaration / definition
>   error C2059 : syntax error : '<'

And also:

> error C2039 : 'map' : is not a member of 'std'

Once I add an include for `std::map`, the errors are reduced:

```
#include <map>

class Registry
{
    template<class configclass>
    std::map<std::wstring, configclass> enumerateSubKeys(std::wstring subKeyName);
}
```

> error C2628 : 'Registry' followed by 'int' is illegal(did you forget a ';' ? )

Which suggests you are missing a semi-colon at the end of the class declaration.